# How is starship armor bonus used in calculating Reflex defense in Star Wars Saga Edition?

Tags: star-wars-saga-edition

In SWSE, the armor bonus is supposed to be part of the Reflex defense, but the numbers don't add up.  For example, the YT-2400 has an armor of +15.  According to what I'm reading, the calculation should go:

10 + Dex bonus + Armor bonus + size modifier

For the YT-2400, this (ostensibly) adds like this:

10 + 4 + 15 - 5 = 24

However, the listed Reflex defense is 19.

Similar discrepancies occur with other stats and with other ships.

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: Hi Matthew, and welcome to RPG Stack Exchange! Check out our [tour] to see how we work here, and when you reach 20 rep you're also welcome to join us in [chat].

Answer (score 1):

OK!  Figured it out!  It took a bunch of digging, link-clicking, and page-turning, but I realized what I was doing wrong.

First, I was using the wrong size modifier; anything of any Colossal size gets a -10 to its Reflex defense.  Period.  (I was using -5).

The size modifier to Damage Threshold for this size vessel is +50.

And the modifier to Grapple is +20.

Too many different numbers for my brain to track, apparently.  Good to go now.  :)